# Adding external parts with heat sink to increase max current of SimpleFOCMini driver (DRV8313)

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, driver, remote-control

**Question:** Is it easily possible with some external MOSFETs or similar things to increase the max current the DRV8313 can handle per phase of a 3 phase BLDC motor? Will be 3 parts enough, or would I need a full 6 FET bridge again? Is it easily possible at all, with only the 3 output signals from the driver? Adding a heatsink to the DRV8313 board will not help much, as it seems to limit the current actually by measuring the current, not the temperature (If I got the datasheet right).

**Background:**
I have some RC project, with arduino controlling 4 engines, directly connected to the wheels. I just wanted to play with the idea of having torque on every wheel, no matter whether the others are in the air, or having friction, by calculating the rotation speed according to the direction of the steering.

I was doing an experiment with steppers, but the ones small enough for the vehicle have very low torque and also very low max speed. No fun with that setup. Now I try with strong but small BLDC motors, like used on drones. Typical ESCs for those are no option, as those are not good for slow moving. I have no gearing between engine and wheel, so I have to be able to turn slow. Open Loop Controller can do this, so I ended up with 4 SimpleFOCMini drivers, that have a pretty simple arduino lib fulfilling all my needs. I built the vehicle in a way, that I need only 2 different rotation speeds, not more, so 6 outputs from arduino are enough.

The motor can handle some 30A, but the driver just 2.5A It is possible to limit the voltage in software, to set the driving current to a low level, even with very low resistance in the motor coils, but of course I would like to have the maximum torque I can squeeze out, at least in heavy moments, e.g. when vehicle is climbing a hill or has to dig out of a hole. I consider to have a switch for low/middle/high current on the remote (which I could set in the software using the voltage limit).

Comment: Why don't you just design a more powerful tripe half-bridge driver?

Comment: Because I'm not very good with that stuff, that's why I ask. Also I can't work with those tiny ICs, no clue how somebody solders 14 legs spread acros less than an inch...

But I have no problem adding some larger FETs, or other discrete parts on a board. Even designed some simple electronics around the Arduino, but mainly basic stuff.

If I look at the complexity of the projects where people built there own ESCs that does not look like the right project size for me. 

Also I need the thing 4 times, so it'd better not cost more than a few bugs.